# creating a new database from vbscript on local

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

I need to do some csv manipulation and using vbscript to do it. Once I am done with my program I need to dump 2000 csv files into database. I want to do this using vbscript. Can someone please help me with my below code. what is wrong with and how i can do it in better way.
At present I am getting invalid Authorization error, which according to google can happen because of multiple reasons.

```
Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=fret;Trusted_Connection=True;"
Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" )
myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
myCommand.CommandText = "create DATABASE TEMP"
myCommand.Execute
myConn.Close
```

Comment: Are you using vbscript or VBA for this task? Why have you tagged the post with both? Also, on which line is the auth error processing?

Comment: @AndrewWynn . Apologies for incorrect tag, its in vbscript. The error is on line 4 (myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING). I am trying to create a database on sql server installed on my local. I am not sure what user name password I am gonna supply, because I am using Windows Authentication to connect via ssms.

Comment: try adding `Integrated Security=SSPI;` see http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/#microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb

Comment: Thanks man. I figured it out. appreciate you taking time and helping me